# how to delete a sprite in an sprite array in pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js

I want to delete a sprite from my sprite array and I tried `myPlane.bullets[index].destroy()` and `myPlane.bullets.shift()`:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < myPlane.bullets.length; index++) {
  if(myPlane.bullets[index].y < -bulletHeight) {
      
    // step 1
    myPlane.bullets[index].destroy() 
      
    // step 2
    myPlane.bullets.shift()
      
    continue
  }
  myPlane.bullets[index].y -= bulletSpeed
}
```

but I think that's not the best way to delete a sprite in an array, it is too fussy.

###### Is there a better way to delete a sprite in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `myPlane.bullets.shift()` will only remove the first element of the array. To remove an element by index you need to use `myPlane.bullets.splice(i, 1)`.

Keep in mind that this affects the original indexes of the objects. If you don't handle it, the for loop will continue increasing and will skip one element.

```js
for (let index = 0; index < myPlane.bullets.length; index++) {
  if (myPlane.bullets[index].y < -bulletHeight) {
      
    // step 1
    myPlane.bullets[index].destroy() 
      
    // step 2
    myPlane.bullets.splice(index, 1)

    index-- // compensate array length mutation
    continue
  }
  myPlane.bullets[index].y -= bulletSpeed
}
```

Generally speaking, you should avoid mutating the array that you are looping through. If you don't keep references to the `bullets` array, here is an alternative where a new filtered array is created:

```js
myPlane.bullets = myPlane.bullets.filter((bullet) => {
  if (bullet.y < -bulletHeight) {
    bullet.destroy()
    return false
  }

  return true
});

for (let index = 0; index < myPlane.bullets.length; index++) {
  myPlane.bullets[index].y -= bulletSpeed
}
```

Comment: emmm, first of all, thanks a lot for modifying my code, that could reduce bug, but when I run a loop function in PIXI.ticker.add(), I just use for loop one time or not filter and for loop, it could save time in the ticker.

I am sorry that maybe I did not describe my question clear. every time I want to delete a sprite object in my common array, I have to run two steps, like code above, it's not elegant, so I think is there a way just use one step to delete it? (both in array and stage). it is maybe from PIXI's API.

Comment: @hanjunyi Three advices: 1. Avoid premature optimization. First make this work and then try to optimize. 2. Make sure your program is not leaking memory. Open devtools and there look in "Memory" tab to see if garbage collector is correctly freeing memory from those destroyed objects (bullets).  3. Try to use `container.removeChild` method inbstead of destroy. See also: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/19815-correct-way-of-deleting-a-display-object/#comment-112400  , https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/30539-correct-way-to-remove-sprites-container/

Comment: I'm assuming that `myPlane` isn't a pixi DisplayObject of any kind, but a custom javascript object that holds the references to the bullets, correct? In that case, you need to perform two actions because you need to modify two different things: your custom object, and the list of children of `bulletsContainer` (`bullet.parent`, I made up the name, we don't know the parent of the bullets from your question).

Comment: @Eduardo Páez Rubio. 
oh! you are right! I love you haha. After reading your answer and docs, finally I get the right way(PIXI.container) to manage the Sprites.